# Struct isKindOfClass

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I find out if a struct is of a specific type? In other words, if I get an object, how do I know that the underluying type is a struct?

```
+(BOOL)isPrimitive:(id)input
{
    return [input isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class] ] || [input isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]] || [input isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
        ||  __IS_THIS_A_STRUCT__ (specifically SEL);
}
```

What should I put in place of **IS_THIS_A_STRUCT**?

Comment: it is not possible to be struct. or you are doing it really wrong. `id` must be a pointer to ObjC object. otherwise your compiler will warn you. However, struct can be wrapped with `NSValue`, maybe this is what you want to test.

Comment: `SEL`'s aren't structs, they're `char *`.  It might be impossible to determine whether something is an object, seeing as I could just pass in some struct with an isa pointer and all would be well.

Comment: I am cloning an object, and some of its properties are of type selector. This method is supposed to transfer over selectors (and strings/dates/etc) to the cloned object. How should I do that?

Comment: @user2453876 you can get the return type of a method and hence the general type (class or relevant C atomic type) of a property. Would that do it?

Comment: Make a new method to do this, or forward the message some other way.  You don't have to write catch-all methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like you know a property and want to act in a certain way if it returns a struct. If so then you could do something like:

```
if(!strcmp([[self class] 
    instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(propertyName)].methodReturnType, 
    @encode(SEL)))
```

`@encode` returns the [type encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) for the named type, which is a C string. `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector` returns an [`NSMethodSignature`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSMethodSignature) which can nominate the return type of that method as an encoded type.

The two type encodings are not guaranteed to have the same identity but will have the same value. So you can use the C function `strcmp` to check that they're the same.

You can use [`NSSelectorFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString) if the selector name is not known at compile time.